# How can I insert mathematical notation through HTML textarea?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to copy and paste mathematical formulas from other websites , the problem is that the formulas change their structure when I paste it to my admin textarea and looks differently in my website.I used CKEditor , but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: These formulas are probably generated by a library or something (unless they are trivial).  You could do a view source of the page to see how they are defined and use the same notation.

Comment: Do you mean some characters that you type in the creditor is changed when you render them on some other page ?

Comment: @Irfan - Use editor for mathematical expression like  [link](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/eqneditor)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [MathJax, a JavaScript display engine](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted), to display math on your website. It is simple to get started just by adding this to your page:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>
```

After that, you can easily start writing mathematical formulas in many notations, i.e. TeX and LaTeX notation, MathML notation, and/or AsciiMath notation.

In fact, StackOverflow uses MathJax as well :)